# How rate of interest affects inflation rate

Tags: compound-interest

Suppose i invest 100000 today.and suppose rate of interest is 12% and inflation rate is 6% . so what amount i will get after 2 year at the rate of 12% and inflation of 6%.

In other word you can say,how the rate of interest affects inflation rate.

Please help me to get this.I'm struggling for this for a long while.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I need answer....

Comment: Related quastion: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/56838/why-adjust-for-inflation-annually-as-opposed-to-realising-it-after-the-holding/56847#56847

Comment: If you need an answer... this must be homework!

Answer (score 2):

With principal, interest rate and inflation

```
p = 100000
r = 0.12
i = 0.06
```

after two years you have

```
p (1 + r)^2 = 125440.00
```

However, accounting for inflation, in today's value that is

```
125440/(1 + i)^2 =  111641.15
```

This is the same as adjusting for inflation after each compounding period, which would be necessary if there were intervening cash flows.

```
year1 =     p (1 + r)/(1 + i) = 105660.38
year2 = year1 (1 + r)/(1 + i) = 111641.15
```

See http://financeformulas.net/Real_Rate_of_Return.html

[image]

also https://money.stackexchange.com/a/56847/11768

The quick and dirty method you may find mentioned elsewhere is

```
p (1 + (r - i))^2 = 112360.00
```

but that's just lazy and wrong.

It is more rigorous to use an extra step calculating `x`

```
x = i (1 + r)/(1 + i)

p (1 + (r - x))^2 = 111641.15
```

*Additional note by RonJohn*

The Q&D method is wrong because `(1 + (r - i))^2 where r=12% and i=6%` reduces to `1.06^2`, whereas `1.12^A` grows faster than `1.06^A`.

Answer (score 2):

Inflation doesn’t affect your nominal investment return at all, only its spending power. If you invest $100,000 for two years at 12% per year, you will have $125,440, whatever the inflation rate is. If the inflation rate for the things you want to buy (which may be different from the headline inflation rate) was 6% per year, then that $125,440 will only buy you as much as $111,641 would have at the time you made the initial investment.

Comment: `10^5 * 1.06^2 = 112,360`, not `111,641`.

Comment: @RonJohn see Chris Degnen's answer for why 112,360 is wrong.

Comment: @ssn `10^5 * 1.06^2 = 112,360` most certainly **is** mathematically correct as to what 10^5 is after two years of inflation.  `111,641` is the answer to a different problem: `1.12^2 / 1.06^2 = 1.11641153`.

Comment: @RonJohn No 111,641 is the answer to *this* problem. 112,360 is how much you should have in `t + 2` to equal 100,000 today. Yes the math is correct isolated - but **that** is the answer to a different problem.

Comment: @ssn you seem to be assuming I don't know the different between `10^5 * 1.06^2` (which is 112,360) and `10^5 * 1.12^2/1.06^2` (which is 111,641).

Comment: @RonJohn definitely not - but your comment, however, indicates this answer we are commenting on is in fact wrong - which it is not.

Comment: @ssn then Mike's answer is confusingly written (which is possible; I've been know to do that...).

Comment: @RonJohn yes - he has left out how to discount the $125,440 to get present value of $111,641.

Answer (score 0):

The balance of your investment investment account will grow at 12% APR no matter what the rate of inflation.

This means that after two years the account value will be 1.12<sup>2</sup> = 1.2544 times more than the starting balance.

But... since the value of money has -- in some economist's delusionally uniform world -- decreased by 6%/annum for two years, you now require 1.06<sup>2</sup> = 1.1236 times more than the starting balance just to be able to buy what you did two years ago.

You'd think that because 12% is 2x as large as 6% that you'd have 2x as much money every year.  Not so, because compounding is a power function while ratios are linear.

The formula for the **yearly percentage difference** between a 12% investment and 6% inflation is calculated by `((1.12^A)-1)/((1.06^A)-1) - 2` where A is the number of years since the start.

This is derived from:

```
1.12^A/1.06^A
```

Correct: I've not mentioned your 100000 starting amount, because it's irrelevant.  Multiply your starting balance (whatever it's size, whether 20 or 80 or 10^5 or 4.2*10^72) by 1.06^A and 1.12^A to get the values for each year `A`.  And naturally, the `.12` and `.06` can be changed to any number you'd like depending on the investment and inflation rates.